# EJB transaction vs. Oracle transaction

Tags: oracle, transactions, ejb

I have a wonder here.
I have a web application with EJBs to communicate with database.
I intend to run it on two distinct application servers (completely distinct servers running on different hardware and everything).
I intend to have them share one single database.

How does it work with transactions? is it a risk that I have two separate servers so two separate EJB transaction repositories and only one database, so one "repository" of database transactions?

Is this safe?

I do know the architecture is not valid, and that there are better ways, but about this EJB vs Oracle transaction, where di I stand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JTA takes place the opposite scenario, I mean, when from 1 EJB context you are interacting with **several transactional resources** (for example, 2 different databases, or JMS servers, or others). This is not your case. JTA takes care to initiate 1 transaction in each one of these resources when a EJB transaction starts, and commit in all of them (or rollback all of them if one fails) along with the EJB transaction.

In your case you can use JTA or not because you have only 1 transactional resource.

Answering your question, **you can safely access from different EJB applications to the same database without risk**, because the integrity of the data is going to be guarranteed by the transactional engine of the database.

When you communicate from an EJB context with, lets say, an EntityManager (that in turn communicates with a database) a Database transaction is automatically started, that is isolated from other transactions started in the Database (for example, from other EJB contexts (your case) or whaterver other application).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if you have EJBs on one server making remote calls to other EJBs on the second server.

If we assume you are simply going to deploy your application to a clustered App Server with two nodes, then XA (two phase commit) isn't relevant, because you can make your app use local EJBs meaning that all communication between EJBs stays on one node.

You need to stick a load balancer infront of the two nodes and it can share the load between the two nodes.

Doing it this way will mean that any single request from a client browser is entirely handled within one node, which will give good performance because you have no remote calls between EJBs.  As such, a single request from the web tier will start a transaction as it enters the EJB container (if required) and that transaction will be committed when the EJB call returns (unless the EJB container determines it needs to rollback due to an exception or explicit call to the context to roll the transaction back).

A simple architecture like this is quite normal and you will find thousands of apps around the world built like this.

As your webapp load increases with more users, you can scale out by adding more and more nodes - the app server manager will ensure that the app is deployed to the new nodes.

The only issue with this architecture is the question of what happens when a node "disappears", say due to a crash or if its taken down for say hardware maintenance.  In this case, a user's web session will be lost, unless you have told the app server to share sessions across nodes.  If you do this, overall performance suffers, because of the continual sharing of session state between nodes.  Alternatively, if this feature isn't activated, you have the problem that successive web requests need to be routed to the same node by the load balancer.

You will know your requirements best and have to choose exactly which architecture you choose.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is through JTA.

JTA supports distributed transactions and their management. To enable a database to participate in a distributed transaction, you have to use XA (transaction aware ) resources.

Here is an article about EJB3 and transactions. Its a bit dated, but it addresses the details

http://java.sys-con.com/node/325149

Just like everything else, there are risks and benefits from using JTA and XA. You are guaranteed data integrity and if your application relies heavily on being transactional, then this might be a worthwhile approach. The downside of this is that XA is less-performant and there is always the risk that some dosnwstream application might end up holding a database lock for a very long time.